# Does an idle btle connection consume energy (on server/sensor side)?

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm reading data from a sensor using `bluepy` and `btle`.
The sensor produces data every 10 seconds and I may need to read data as little as every 5m.

Should I keep a `btle` connection open all the time and just read data every 5 minutes or should I re-create a new connection every 5 minutes and close it as soon as I get the data? Which option is more energy efficient?

Please provide some source for the answer and make sure to cover the following sub-questions:

- does an idle btle consume any energy, server side?
- does the setup of a new connection consume lot of energy, server side?

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky question because this is dependent on a lot of parameters.

A *Peripheral* (which is both BLE LL *Slave* and GATT *Server*) has mainly two active states:

- Advertising: Peripheral broadcasts packets on advertising channels periodically and listens immediately after each advertising packet in case a Central (BLE LL Master) issues a connection request. Consumption-related parameters: advertisement interval, advertising data (payload).
- Connected: Central and Peripheral have a common channel-hopping and time-slotting pattern and agree to exchange at least one packet periodically (spec call this a *connection event*) to keep the connection alive. Between *connection events*, all that consumes power on the Peripheral side is its precise clock: RTC (a few µA). Consumption-related parameters: connection interval (period between two *connection events* where packets must be exchanged), slave latency (number of *connection events* a slave is allowed to miss before this is an error).

Moving from *Advertising* state to *Connected* state requires exchanging packets, but also requires some processing on both sides. It involves between 6 and 30 packets, cryptography calculations (if using secure connections), some tricky timing calculations, etc. This implies Radio and CPU power consumption.

One last parameter is real-time requirement: does it need *fast* delivery or is a sensor reading latency in seconds is acceptable? Think about the difference between a temperature reading for long-term room monitoring and a passive infrared sensor reading that gives instantaneous presence information to raise an alarm. The former can cope with 5-second delivery, the latter may not.

So you are facing a tradeoff between keeping connection alive, which basically requires sending an *empty packet* every now and then, and restarting *advertisement* + *connection establishment* every 5 minutes.

For exact details about breaking down power consumption of a BLE SoC, you may be interested in other questions like
[How can I estimate the power consumption of a BLE module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725225/how-can-i-estimate-the-power-consumption-of-a-ble-module/37082360#37082360) and [Bluetooth LE - deciding client vs. server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893422/bluetooth-le-deciding-client-vs-server/40894280#40894280)

If you accept slow reconnections (which you should, if you have no real-time requirements), you may have low duty cycle *advertisement* (*advertising interval* of 100s of ms), which will save power when there is no connection. You should also avoid advertising eternally and stop advertising where no Central creates a connection to you.

When *connected*, you may benefit from *slave latency*: having a 50 ms *connection interval* with a *slave latency* of 19 allows an idle-yet-connected slave to wake radio and CPU up once every second, which will make the overall radio consumption negligible in *connected* state (and even lower than the consumption of *advertising* state), and yet allow to deliver sensor data in less than 50 ms when it becomes available.

If I had to design such a system, I would probably keep connection open as much as possible, but if it closes for some reason, wait for the next 5 minute data point to be available to send before restarting advertisement, and stop advertising after 10-30 seconds if not connected until the next 5 minute data point.

Note: *Connection parameters* (*connection interval*, *slave latency*) are mandated by the *Link-layer master* (i.e. *Central*).

Comment: Another thing that is important for connection setup is the duty cycle of the initiator, i.e. its scan window and scan interval. A high duty cycle will reduce the number of advertising packets needed that the peripheral has to send when it wants to connect.

Comment: @emil, agreed. Anyway, here central power seems not to be a problem, so even 100% duty cycle on the scanner side seems affordable, then I did not address it.